# Including variables in keys and values in PHP

Tags: php

Is there any way to shorten this array

`array = [ 'student1' => 'id1', 'student2' => 'id2',];`

to something like this?

`array = ['student' . $n => 'id' . $n];`

I will appreciate if you give me words to search!

Edit:
Sorry for the poor explanation. I wanted to do something like this:

```
$array = ['student'.$n => 'id'.$n];  
echo($array['student1']);  //id1
```

Comment: What is the problem with your own example? It should work

Comment: Search `concatenation`, `variables`, `string`..

Comment: what you actually want is not clear ? generally `id1` is not id and `student1` is not student name

Comment: `for` loop, but you should better use a multidimensional array `['students' => ['id1' , 'id2']]`

Comment: What's the problem, this works. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f913d6edef9c49c6f3b8266f7b5272242ecfd8fd

Answer (score 0):

Loop the number of students you need and build the array with array_merge.

```
$students = 10;
$arr = [];
for($i = 1; $i<=$students; $i++){
    $arr = array_merge($arr, ['student' . $i => 'id' . $i]);
}

var_dump($arr);
```

output:

```
array(10) {
  ["student1"]=>
  string(3) "id1"
  ["student2"]=>
  string(3) "id2"
  ["student3"]=>
  string(3) "id3"
  ["student4"]=>
  string(3) "id4"
  ["student5"]=>
  string(3) "id5"
  ["student6"]=>
  string(3) "id6"
  ["student7"]=>
  string(3) "id7"
  ["student8"]=>
  string(3) "id8"
  ["student9"]=>
  string(3) "id9"
  ["student10"]=>
  string(4) "id10"
}
```

Comment: Just `$arr['student' . $i] = 'id' . $i;` would do just fine…